# Laravel: error with {{url()}} embedded in html

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to do the following in my blade.php but I get a syntax error:

```
      <a class="btn btn-info" role="button" href="{{ url('/Animal/{{$animal->id}}/edit')}}">Edit Profile</a>
```

The error is to do with the href attribute I think, how do I correct the syntax?

Error I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIQ0E.png)

Comment: could add names to their routes and use the helper `route('routename', parameters);` It would be more readable in every way. for example `route('animals.edit',$animal)`

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code, please try this one.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" role="button" href="{{ url('/Animal/' . $animal->id . '/edit')}}">Edit Profile</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a syntax error in your code. You can't use `{{ }}` inside another `{{ }}`.

You have access to php variable inside this first `{{ }}`.

Use `""` instead of `''` to use php variables inside a string.

```
<a 
    class="btn btn-info"
    role="button" 
    href="{{ url("/Animal/$animal->id/edit") }}"
>
    Edit Profile
</a>
```